# How to break long values in yaml file?

Tags: yaml

I have yaml file from an ansible role, when I run yamllinst, it output as follows:

> 22:81     error    line too long (81 > 80 characters)  (line-length)
> 29:81     error    line too long (109 > 80 characters)  (line-length)

This is part of the file (I've commented the lines that has errors, that comments are no real part of the file)

```
- name: Check that all the variables needed are defined
  assert:
    that:
      - kimai_version is defined
      - kimai_app_env is defined
      - kimai_user is defined
      - kimai_group is defined
      - kimai_home is defined
      - kimai_private is defined
      - ( kimai_docroot is defined ) and ( kimai_docroot | basename == "public" ) # Line 29
      - kimai_dbuser is defined
      - kimai_dbpass is defined
      - kimai_dbhost is defined
      - kimai_dbport is defined
      - kimai_dbname is defined
      - kimai_notify_from is defined
      - ( kimai_email_transport is defined ) and ( kimai_email_transport is regex("^smtp|sendmail|gmail|$") ) # Line 29
      - kimai_email_host is defined
      - kimai_email_port is defined
      - kimai_user_registration is defined
```

The question [How do I break a string in YAML over multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/how-do-i-break-a-string-in-yaml-over-multiple-lines) is a bit different because in that case, the key has only one value.

How can I break the 22 and 29th lines to shorten them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how the linked question is any different, you can of course do

```yaml
- name: Check that all the variables needed are defined
  assert:
    that:
      - kimai_version is defined
      - kimai_app_env is defined
      - kimai_user is defined
      - kimai_group is defined
      - kimai_home is defined
      - kimai_private is defined
      - >-
        ( kimai_docroot is defined ) and
        ( kimai_docroot | basename == "public" )
      - kimai_dbuser is defined
      - kimai_dbpass is defined
      - kimai_dbhost is defined
      - kimai_dbport is defined
      - kimai_dbname is defined
      - kimai_notify_from is defined
      - >-
        ( kimai_email_transport is defined ) and
        ( kimai_email_transport is regex("^smtp|sendmail|gmail|$") )
      - kimai_email_host is defined
      - kimai_email_port is defined
      - kimai_user_registration is defined
```

Since the content is not overly complex, you can also use multiline plain scalars:

```yaml
- name: Check that all the variables needed are defined
  assert:
    that:
      - kimai_version is defined
      - kimai_app_env is defined
      - kimai_user is defined
      - kimai_group is defined
      - kimai_home is defined
      - kimai_private is defined
      - ( kimai_docroot is defined ) and
        ( kimai_docroot | basename == "public" )
      - kimai_dbuser is defined
      - kimai_dbpass is defined
      - kimai_dbhost is defined
      - kimai_dbport is defined
      - kimai_dbname is defined
      - kimai_notify_from is defined
      - ( kimai_email_transport is defined ) and
        ( kimai_email_transport is regex("^smtp|sendmail|gmail|$") )
      - kimai_email_host is defined
      - kimai_email_port is defined
      - kimai_user_registration is defined
```

In both cases, the line breaks will be parsed as single spaces.

Comment: thanks I didn't know that were so easy :)